# AS3: How to convert a Vector to an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, vector

What's the nicest way to convert a Vector to an Array in Actionscript3?

The normal casting syntax doesn't work:

```
var myVector:Vector.<Foo> = new Vector();
var myArray:Array = Array(myVector); // calls the top-level function Array()
```

due to the existance of the Array function. The above results in an array, but it's an array with a single element consisting of the original Vector.

Which leaves the slightly more verbose:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();
for each (var elem:Foo in myVector) {
    myArray.push(elem);
}
```

which is fine, I guess, though a bit wordy. Is this the canonical way to do it, or is there a toArray() function hiding somewhere in the standard library?

Comment: for(var i:int; i < muVector.length; ++i){} may be faster.  But there is no other solution.

Comment: Also, using myArray[myArray.length] = elem; is faster than using push().

Answer (score 24, accepted):

your approach is the fastest ... if you think it's to verbose, then build a utility function ... :)

**edit:**

To build a utility function, you will probably have to drop the type as follows:

```
function toArray(iterable:*):Array {
     var ret:Array = [];
     for each (var elem:Foo in iterable) ret.push(elem);
     return ret;
}
```

Comment: Building a utility function isn't an option since it couldn't apply to any type of Vector... unless anyone knows of a way to make a function that takes as a parameter ANY type of Vector?

Answer (score 20):

There is a function called forEach which both Vector and Array has which you can use. Basically it calls a function for each element in the vector. This is how it works:

```
var myVector:Vector.<Foo> = new Vector();
var myArray:Array = [];

myVector.forEach(arrayConverter);

function arrayConverter(element:*, index:int, array:Array):void{
    myArray[myArray.length] = element;
}
```

But I couldn't find a function which just moves all the values from the Vector to an Array. Another solution could be that you create a class which extends the Vector class and then you have a public function called toArray() and then you have that code in that function so you don't have to write it each time you want to convert.

[Vector documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Vector.html)

**Edit:** Found this old question today and thought it would be interesting to do a benchmark test of all the different methods this sunday morning.

I used a vector with 1000000 items in and made 2 tests for each loop. One using the built in array functions push and one using regular array operations.

- For loop, not push: **520** ms
- For loop, push: **1027** ms
- Foreach loop, not push: **1753** ms
- Foreach loop, push: **2264** ms
- While loop, not push: **2775** ms
- While loop, not push: **3282** ms
- Util loop, not push: **4059** ms
- Util loop, push: **4570** ms

And here is a benchmark using 1000 items:

- For loop, not push: **1** ms
- For loop, push: **2** ms
- Foreach loop, not push: **2** ms
- Foreach loop, push: **3** ms
- While loop, not push: **3** ms
- While loop, not push: **4** ms
- Util loop, not push: **4** ms
- Util loop, push: **5** ms

Basically it's when you get over 10 000 items you start to see the real difference. So between 0 and 10 000 items it doesn't really matter which you use.

```
package
{
    public class Loops{
        public static function forLoop(vector:Vector.<Foo>, usePush:Boolean = false):Array{
            var result:Array = [];

            for(var i:int = 0; i < vector.length; i++){
                if(usePush){
                    result.push(vector[i]);
                }else{
                    result[result.length] = vector[i];
                }
            }

            return result;          
        }

        public static function foreachLoop(vector:Vector.<Foo>, usePush:Boolean):Array{
            var result:Array = [];

            for each(var key:String in vector){
                if(usePush){
                    result.push(vector[key]);
                }else{
                    result[result.length] = vector[key];
                }
            }

            return result;          
        }

        public static function whileLoop(vector:Vector.<Foo>, usePush:Boolean):Array{
            var result:Array = [];

            var i:int = 0;
            while(i < vector.length){
                if(usePush){
                    result.push(vector[i]);
                }else{
                    result[result.length] = vector[i];
                }
            }

            return result;                      
        }

        public static function arrayUtilLoop(vector:Vector.<Foo>, usePush:Boolean):Array{
            var result:Array = [];

            function arrayUtilForeach(element:*, index:int, array:Array):void{
                if(usePush){
                    array.push(element);
                }else{
                    array[result.length] = element;
                }
            }           

            vector.forEach(arrayUtilForeach);

            return result;          
        }
    }
}
```

I used the getTimer function to do the benchmark, so it might not be 100% accurate but there's so much difference between the different loops so I don't think it matters.

I hope someone found this useful.

Comment: very nice, but extremely slow ... you realize how many calls this makes?

Comment: yes, in my opinion it's nicer than using a for/for each loop. It's a function call for each element in the Vector. How much slower exactly is this approach?

Comment: you don't want to call myVector.length in every loop. by removing it i've more than doubled the performance, http://pastebin.com/0waTqaER
checking length each time =  491
not checking length each time =  209

Comment: Just a note: for each does not guarantee any particular order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618966/for-each-loop-as3-is-the-direction-guaranteed Although it may be that the as3 implementation does actually behave as desired.

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
var myArray:Array = [];
myArray.push.apply(null, myVector);
```

or

```
var myArray:Array = new Array().concat(myVector);
```

Comment: This constructs a one-element array with the vector as the first value...

Answer (score 3):

for each will not guarantee that the order of your items will be the same.
for in should give you a closer match.

```
    private var _vector:*;

    public function VectorUtil(vector:*)
    {
        _vector = vector;
    }

    public function toArray():Array
    {
        var a:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < _vector.length; ++i)
            a.push(_vector[i]);
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Vaukalak second answer not only works but is much faster than the top voted answer here, I've massaged it a little as [] produces fractionally faster array construction than new Array(). Also included below is the best way to create a Vector from an Array too.

```
// make a Vector from an array
var toVector : Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>(['a','b','c']) 

// populate an array from a Vector
var toArray : Array = [].concat(toVector);
```

**Please note, this only seems to work with flash 11**

Comment: This actually constructs a one-element array with the vector as the first value.

Comment: How does this wrong answer have so many votes? As jameshfisher points out, the behavior is incorrect. Is StackOverflow turning into a trolling site?

Comment: @Jonathan, the answer to your first question is that this is a flash related question. The majority of the community are very junior developers.

Answer (score 0):

a function call for each element in the Vector would be a LOT slower, particularly in a longer Vector.  however, these examples are probably all equivalent, unless you're dealing with a fairly long Vector/Array -- legibility and ease of use are generally more important than optimization.

that said, i think the fastest way is to use a while loop with an iterator compared against 0.

```
var myArray:Array = new Array(myVector.length);
var i:int=myVector.length;
while (i--) {
    myArray[i] = myVector[i];
}
```

unfortunately, you can't stuff this technique into a method for ease of repeated use, because there's no way to specify a Vector method parameter of a generic base type.... :(

Answer (score -4):

If you have a vector of strings, you could do:

```
myArray = myVec.join(",").split(",");
```

for a quick and dirty Array conversion.

Comment: What if your strings have commas in them?

Comment: the splitter doesn't matter, so myVect.join(":|:").split(":|:") works just as well...

Answer (score -13):

var a:Array = some_vector as Array;

Comment: A Vector cannot be casted as an Array. This code would return null.