# What is Foo in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have seen it many times like here [AS3: How to convert a Vector to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107809/as3-how-to-convert-a-vector-to-an-array) and have never really learnt about it in any tutorials.

Even searched on google and got no results - http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=Foo+in+AS3&meta=

is it some sort of object or variable type that I have been missing?

Or is it something that comes with some external library?

When I compile my code with Foo I get

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Foo.
```

Thanks

Comment: This made my day! Many years ago when I started working w/unix, I wondered the same thing. What is all this "foo, bar, baz" stuff that I saw my friends typing. This was before the internet was popular (my friends were really geeks). I'm sure you're not alone in wondering what it all means, each new generation of programmers has probably wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an actual type, just a placeholder to be useful for giving an example. Sometimes referred to as a [metasyntactic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html) type.

So, you have to substitute an **actual type** in place of `Foo` when attempting to compile the code, else it won't compile, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Foo is just a term used in programmer's slang for variables examples when the name doesn't really matter, or to represent a value that's not important.

You can read about the "Foo" term at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt

Answer (score 0):

[**Foobar** - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar):

> the use of foo in a programming context is generally credited to the
>   Tech Model Railroad Club (TMRC) from circa 1960. However, the precise
>   relationship of these terms is not known with certainty, and several
>   anecdotal theories have been advanced to identify them.