# AS3: short and simple Vector<String> to Array convertation

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I need to convert `Vector<String>` to `Array`.

I know the this can be done via any cycle. but in my case it's `Vector.<String>`, there is may be no need to run cycles

At this pont, I guess this is very shor and simple way to do this:

```
var vector:Vector.<String> = new <String>["111", "111", "111", "111"];
var array:Array = vector.join(",").split(",");
```

Ofcource, you need to be shure, thet separator will never be the part of any `String` on `Vector`. This can force you to set multi-characters separator, like `',,,'`. does this effects on speed?
Is it ok? Is it fast anough?

Comment: Only you can answer if it is fast enough for your purposes. Also, here's a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107809/as3-how-to-convert-a-vector-to-an-array) that seems to answer your question as well. personally, i would go with a for loop that just puts the elements in the array (not through push() though, apparently that's slower)

Comment: thnx for response. I know the this can be done view any cycle. but in my case it's `Vector.<String>`, there is may be no need to run cycles

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your function (I called it "short") and the "classic" way with a cycle. Results:

```
[trace] 10000 elem : classic : 2
[trace] 10000 elem : short : 26
[trace] 100000 elem : classic : 17
[trace] 100000 elem : short : 50
[trace] 1000000 elem : classic : 153
[trace] 1000000 elem : short : 542
```

So, I can't recommend to use your way on the big data sets, but it will be OK on the small sets of data.

Comment: I guess, the last number in each line is time to execute... In my case array length will be <100. one way or enother, I'll have in mind that. tnx for research

Comment: Yep, it is a spend time in "ms".